# C# хронология активных окон Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с задачей, для которой не смог пока найти эффективного решения. Может быть, сообщество подскажет, в каком направлении копать? Задачка простая на первый взгляд, но эффективного решения пока не нашел.

Итак, ситуация - есть чужое ПО (А), работающее в SDI-режиме, т.е. каждый инстанс такого EXE работает со своим документом. И есть наше ПО (Б), отдельным EXE, которое автоматизирует некоторую работу в одном из открытых окон первого ПО. 
В системе может быть запущено несколько процессов типа А. Сейчас, что бы программа Б знала, в каком окне А работать, выводится окно диспетчера, в котором отображается список программ типа А, и пользователь самостоятельно выбирает, в каком окне типа А будет отрабатывать программа Б.
Именно этот момент и нужно исключить: программа Б должна понимать, с каким именно окном А работал пользователь до того момента, как переключился в окно Б.
Т.е. сценарий работы может быть таким (как пример):

1. Пользователь запустил программу А1.
2. Пользователь запустил программу А2.
3. Пользователь запустил браузер.
4. Пользователь запустил программу А3.
5. Пользователь переключился в программу А1.
6. Система запустила что-то по расписанию (обновления, например)
7. Пользователь запустил нашу программу Б, и нажал в её окне кнопку выполнения действий.
8. Сейчас выводится окно диспетчера, в котором пользователь должен выбрать в какой программе, А1, А2 или А3 нужно выполнять эти действия.

Задача поставлена таким образом, чтобы исключить п. 8 и программа Б сама могла выполнить действия в окне А1 без участия пользователя, т.к. последний инстанс типа А, с которым работал пользователь - это именно А1.

Сейчас решение мне видится в создании некоего третьего приложения В, которое будет висеть в памяти постоянно, с неким интервалом получать список процессов типа А, и каким-то образом производить сортировку этого списка, где элемент с индексом 0 будет соответствовать последнему использованному процессу типа А.
Тогда приложение Б сможет обратится к скрытому диспетчеру В (назовем его так) и получить handle окна нужного инстанса типа А.

Но данное решение мне видится очень ненадежным и кривым, т.к. не очень очевидно, как именно выполнять сортировку списка (по возрастанию Handle процесса вообще не вариант ведь), а с высокой частотой опрашивать систему, какое сейчас окно активно, и если это окно типа А, то выносить его вверх списка тоже кажется неэффективным.

Эффективным решением оказалось бы, если приложение типа А при активации собственного окна само выставляло бы флаг собственной активизации (условно, писало бы свой Handle в файл), а приложение Б считывало бы это значение и таим образом знало бы, с каким окном ему работать. Беда в том, что заставить делать такое действие чужое приложение мне не видится возможным (да, я знаю, что, вероятно, можно было бы сделать инжект своей DLL к процессу типа А и уже там выполнить нужные действия, но этот путь тоже мне не видится очень уж простым).

Благодарю за потраченное время на прочтение и оказанное внимание, буду рад любым рекомендациям и советам.

Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуй, [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) сможет помочь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо за ссылочку на эту функцию, мне думается, это то, что нужно. Нашел даже [демо-проект](https://gist.github.com/fjl/4080259). Работает. Оформляйте ответ )

Comment: Ответ в виде ссылки не годится. Лучше вы оформите, с кусочком кода.

Comment: @BlackWitcher: И правда, напишите ответ с кодом, будет полезно всем.

Comment: @VladD, разместил заготовку кода решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендуя на идеальность решения, всё же публикую демо-код в качестве ответа.
Спасибо [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov) за верно заданное направление.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

....

static class Program
{
    #region Объявление WinApi-констант и функций

    private const int WINEVENT_INCONTEXT = 4;
    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    private const int WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS = 2;
    private const int WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD = 1;
    private const int EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;

    //Это call-back для нашего хука:
    delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook,
        uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject,
        int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin,
        uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc,
        WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,
        uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd,
        StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

    #endregion

    //Хук
    private static IntPtr hookHandle;

    //Главная форма приложения
    private static fmMain mainForm;

    //Точка входа в приложение
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //Создаём главную форму
        mainForm = new fmMain();

        //Вешаем хук
        hookHandle = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
            EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero,
            WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

        //Запускаем приложение
        Application.Run(mainForm);

        //Снимаем хук
        UnhookWinEvent(hookHandle);
    }

    //Вспомогательные функции для получения сведений о перехваченных окнах и процессах
    private static string GetProcessName(int pid)
    {
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        return p.ProcessName;
    }

    private static uint GetPIDbyHwnd(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        return pid;
    }

    //Реализация callback для хука - основная обработка именно тут:
    private static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
        IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild,
        uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        //Фильтр по типу события - перехватываем сообщение, когда какое-либо 
        //окно в системе становится активным (окном переднего плана)
        if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
        {
            //Посредством класса StringBuilder готовим буфер для получения заголовка окна
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);

            //Получаем заголовок активного окна в буфер
            GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

            //По хэндлу активного окна получаем Process Identifier (PID)
            var PID = (int)GetPIDbyHwnd(hwnd);

            //Зная PID - получим имя процесса:  
            var processName = GetProcessName(PID);

            //Выводим полученные сведения в форму:
            mainForm.m_list.Items.Insert(0,
                $"Окно HWND={hwnd}, ProcessName=\"{processName}\", заголовок окна: " + sb.ToString());            
        }
    }
}
```

На главной форме ничего нет, кроме контрола ListBox с именем `m_list`. У самой формы для удобства свойство `TopMost` выставлено в `true`.